Compatibility problem between mangoose 8.4.4 and Angular 18 SSR (node)
I recently built a project from scratch : Angular 18 app (SSR). The project includes some libraries imported from another more achieve project (copy pasting the package.json).
I set up my application (in server.ts), performing then
ng build 

and finally a
nodemon dist/<projectname>/server/server.mjs 

to rend the app on localhost.
My app got crashed every time i tried to render my server.mjs with the following result :
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
  at Function.getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
  at file:///C:../server/server.mjs:107:202540
  at file:///C:../server/chunk-GUTDEJWW.mjs:2:1056
  at ...

I figured out that the problem came from the following line of code :
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

Node version : 20.12.2
mongoose version 8.4.4
I tried to retrograt mongoose to 6.8.4 (as my old project) but the problem persists.
If someone knows why mongoose 8 is not compatible with my Angular 18 or if knows something, i would like to hear it.

I found a (temporarily) solution.
I downgraded once again from 6.4.2 mongoose to 5.13.22 and it solved my issue.
The commands if needed :
npm uninstall mongoose --save
npm install mongoose@5 --save

